# Making a password program in python

Tags: python, passwords, uppercase, lowercase

I am making a case sensitive password program in python in which the password must have an upper case letter, a lower case letter and must be 8 characters minimum. Here is the code:

```
password = input("Please enter a password:")
upperFlag = False
lowerFlag = False
while len(password) < 8:
    try:
        password = input("Password not long enough")
    except:
        print("Error")
for char in password:
    if char == char.upper():
        upperFlag = True
        print("Up")

    elif char == char.lower():
        lowerFlag = True
```

The code is just a concept right now, that is why I have written the code to print for upper case letters. My question is how do I get the program to only print this statement once, instead of printing for each character? (e.g "Up","Up","Up" etc)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're setting a flag anyway, just print at the end if the flag is set.

```
for char in password:
    if char.isupper():
        upperFlag = True
    else:
        lowerFlag = True
if upperFlag:
    print("Up")
```

Alternatively instead of an explicit loop, you can use a comprehension like this:

```
if any(char.isupper() for char in password):
    print("Up")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must just make a test to see if you already print the 'Up' statement.

```
if not upperFlag:
     upperFlag = True
     print('Up')
```

And don't forget to set upperFlag to False at the start of your code or you'll get a NameError

Answer (score -1):

Simply insert a `break` statement after `print("Up")`:

```
password = input("Please enter a password:")
upperFlag = False
lowerFlag = False
while len(password) < 8:
    try:
        password = input("Password not long enough")
    except:
        print("Error")
for char in password:
    if char == char.upper():
        upperFlag = True
        print("Up")
        break #<-- insert break here

    elif char == char.lower():
        lowerFlag = True
```

Comment: This will fail to detect lowercase letters if any come after the first uppercase one...